# Distribution of partial sums of square normal distributions should be chi^2

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Can we simulate using Mathematica the fact that the distribution of partial sums of square normal distributions should be chi^2? 
Can we plot the way the distributions of the partial sums of square normal distribution is getting close to the chi^2 distribution.

Comment: I have done something similar with the uniform distributions but this was much easy since I found the function uniformsumdistribution. Here I have square normals!

Comment: try `m = 20; TransformedDistribution[Total[Array[x[#]^2 &, {m}]], 
 Array[x[#] &, {m}] \[Distributed]   ProductDistribution[{NormalDistribution[], m}]]`

Comment: If I plot chi^2 with the following code:
Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[PDF[NoncentralChiSquareDistribution[20, \[Lambda]], 
    x], {\[Lambda], {0}}], {x, 0, 20}, Filling -> Axis]

Comment: I do not get the same thing (but I should) by ploting the code you gave me (modified a little):
new[n_] := 
 TransformedDistribution[Total[Array[x[#]^2 &, {n}]], 
  Array[x[#] &, {n}] \[Distributed] 
   ProductDistribution[{NormalDistribution[], n}]]

Plot[Evaluate[PDF[new@#, x] & /@ Range[20]], {x, 0, 20}, 
 PlotStyle -> (ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, 20}}] /@ Range[20]), 
 Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 500]

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: Related:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269922/distribution-of-the-sum-of-squared-independent-normal-random-variables.  Are your normal distributions "standard normals" (mean zero, variance 1) or do all of the normal distributions have the same mean and variance?  Please give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the underlying normal distributions are independent, standard normal

```
distr[n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{x, vars},
  vars = Array[x, n];
  TransformedDistribution[
   Total[vars^2],
   Thread[vars \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]]]

Table[distr[n], {n, 4}]

(*  {ChiSquareDistribution[1], ChiSquareDistribution[2], ChiSquareDistribution[3],
  ChiSquareDistribution[4]}  *)
```

`distr[n]` is `ChiSquareDistribution[n]`.

Additional verification,

```
And @@ Table[
  distr[n] == ChiSquareDistribution[n],
  {n, 50}]

(*  True  *)
```

**EDIT:** Generalizing for arbitrary standard deviation for the underlying normal distribution

```
distr2[n_Integer?Positive] := Module[{x, vars}, vars = Array[x, n];
  TransformedDistribution[Total[vars^2], 
   Thread[vars \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, s]],
   Assumptions -> {s > 0}]]

Table[distr2[n], {n, 4}]

(*  {TransformedDistribution[\[FormalX]^2, \[FormalX] \[Distributed] 
   NormalDistribution[0, s], Assumptions -> {s > 0}], 
 ExponentialDistribution[1/(2 s^2)], GammaDistribution[3/2, 2 s^2], 
 GammaDistribution[2, 2 s^2]}  *)
```

It is clear that `distr2[n]` is equivalent to `GammaDistribution[n/2, 2s^2]` for `n > 2`

```
And @@ Assuming[{z > 0, s > 0},
  Table[distr2[n] ==
     GammaDistribution[n/2, 2 s^2],
    {n, 3, 50}] // FullSimplify]

(*  True  *)
```

However, comparing the `PDF`s shows that the distributions are equivalent for all positive integers

```
And @@ Assuming[{z > 0, s > 0},
  Table[PDF[distr2[n], z] ==
     PDF[GammaDistribution[n/2, 2 s^2], z] //
    Simplify, {n, 50}]]

(*  True  *)
```